# MongoDB is saving my model's properties as Objects. What's going on?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async-await, axios

I’ve got an asnyc function that retrieves data from the Twitch API and stores that data into an array, and that array is returned. When I console log the array, I see the data inside the async function as intended.

[Here is the array data that is logged into the console. Note, these were called in SeedDB().](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTCBR.png)

However, there is an issue. When I seed the database, I pass the properties of the model (title: String, summary: String, artworks: Array) by calling the function. The function's indexed values should each correspond with String, String, and Array. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case, as they seem to be saved as objects.

[In MongoDB, they get saved as objects.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5eyh.png)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const axios = require('axios').default;
const Game = require('../models/game'); // Import game Model.

const gameQuery = 'fields name, summary, artworks; where name = "Bloodborne";';

// Connect to MongoDB
const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gameApp');
        console.log('MongoDB connection successful!')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('There was an error...:')
        handleError(error);
    }
}

const fetchGameData = async (index) => {
    const gameData = []
    const config = {
        url: 'https://api.igdb.com/v4/games/',
        headers: {
          'Client-ID': 'SECRET',
          'Authorization': 'SECRET'
        },
        data : gameQuery
      };
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(config.url, config.data, config);
        for (let resp of response.data){
            gameData.push(resp.name, resp.summary, resp.artworks)
        }
        return gameData[index];
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Uh oh, there's been an error...:");
        console.log(err);
    }
}

const seedDB = async() => {
    await connectDB()
    await Game.deleteMany({})
    const Bloodborne = new Game({
        title: JSON.stringify(fetchGameData([0]).then(value => console.log(value))),
        summary: JSON.stringify(fetchGameData([1]).then(value => console.log(value))),
        artworks: JSON.stringify(fetchGameData([2]).then(value => console.log(value)))
    })
    await Bloodborne.save()
    console.log('saved')
}
seedDB()
```

Notice, they're saved as empty objects. If anyone could help, I would appreciate it!

I've tried debugging this for hours. Apparently, JSON.stringify() will return an object, which could be a culprit - however, I need the data as Strings, not JSON data. I've tried checking my awaits, but I believe those are fine...

Comment: please share relevant server code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you are trying to put the value to the JSON.stringify()

```
 const Bloodborne = new Game({
        title: JSON.stringify(fetchGameData([0]).then(value => console.log(value))),
        summary: JSON.stringify(fetchGameData([1]).then(value => console.log(value))),
        artworks: JSON.stringify(fetchGameData([2]).then(value => console.log(value)))
    })
```

this actually returns the function "fetchGameData" as a promise to JSON.stringify() and not the value that you actually want. that's why it's showing an empty object

```
JSON.stringify(fetchGameData([0]).then(value => console.log(value))),
```

one thing you can do to fix it is this

since your function is asnyc you can use await in the JSON.stringify function like this

```
const Bloodborne = new Game({
        title: JSON.stringify(await fetchGameData([0])),
        summary: JSON.stringify(await fetchGameData([1])),
        artworks: JSON.stringify(await fetchGameData([2]))
    })
```

this should await the value of the fetchGameData function then supply the value to JSON.stringify()

Comment: Thank you! That works, mostly. I just realized something though.

[Postman API data](https://i.ibb.co/DgyT6pc/Screenshot-2023-08-16-at-10-42-57-AM.png)

I noticed that title, summary, and artworks are of types String, String, Array.  Therefore, do I not need to use JSON.stringify, since the data I'm retrieving is of their proper types (not actual JSON)? 

Therefore, it can be:

        title: await fetchGameData([0]),
        summary: await fetchGameData([1]),
        artworks: await fetchGameData([2])

(Note: I have changed my 'Artworks: String' to be 'Artworks: Array')